# Function for normalizing Canadian postal codes is returning unexpected results

Tags: php, normalization

I'm trying to normalize user input for Canadian postal codes.

The end goal is to get all input as A3A 3A3 - 7 characters, capitalized, with the first group letter number letter, second group as number letter number.

Users will sometimes use o or O for the number 0, or vice versa, so here is my function:

```
   $zip = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['zip']);
   if (!empty($zip)) {
       //if the format is A3A3A3, split it into two groups
        if (strlen($zip) == 6) {
            $zip = substr($zip, 0, 3) . " " . substr($zip, 3, 3);           
        }
       //now lets make sure there is only a empty space between groups
        if (strlen($zip) == 7) {
            $zip[3] = " ";
        }
       //let's put their o's, O's and 0's in the right places
        if ($zip[1] == ("O" || "o")) {
            $zip[1] = '0';
        }
        if ($zip[4] == ('O'||'o')) {
            $zip[4] = '0';
        }
        if ($zip[6] == ('O'||'o')) {
            $zip[6] = '0';
        }

        if ($zip[0] == '0') {
            $zip[0] = 'O';
        }
        if ($zip[2] == '0') {
            $zip[2] = 'O';
        }
        if ($zip[5] == '0') {
            $zip[5] = 'O';
        }
       //uppercase all the letters
        strtoupper($zip);
   }
```

The first tests I ran were of the sort:

input[0o0 O0o] => output[O0O 0O0]

Everything looks good I said to myself, it's working! But then I tried a normal postal code and keep getting unexpected results:

input[S7K3K1] => output[S0K 0K0]

I can't figure out why the code is deciding that ($zip[1] == ('O' || 'o') is true when $zip[1] == 7.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Also, if you see a better way of normalizing this input, please share!

Comment: One problem with your code (apart from the issue you've mentioned): Canadian postal codes do not include the letter "O" at all (or the letters "D", "F", "I", "Q", or "U"). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada. Your code would benefit from taking the format specification into account and including code to handle cases where a user has entered something that is not a postal code at all (eg. what if they enter a US zip code?).

Comment: Right - my plan is to handle many scenarios with front-end validation. But, the less validation you can use, the easier it is for users. So i.e. if they had entered SOK3K1 instead of S0K3K1, I'd rather just accept it and normalize it.

Comment: Also in some cases we will get data from 3rd parties which could arrive in the same format as the above example.

Comment: Ok, but you're still going to need to handle the same scenarios on the back end - remember, the user can bypass your validation and send whatever data they like to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //let's put their o's, O's and 0's in the right places
    if ($zip[1] == ("O" || "o")) {
        $zip[1] = '0';
    }
```

This code does not do what you think – your comparison logic are wrong, because so is your understanding of the `||` operator.

Use `console.log(("O" || "o"))` and see what you get in console – ooops, that’s just the letter `O`. Why? Because the `||` logical or operator in JS returns the first value that is not false-y.

You need to either write two individual comparisons here, and or-conjoin those – `$zip[1] == "O" || $zip[1] == "o"`, or use an array with possible values and then check whether your variable value is among those (but the latter would be a bit over the top here).

Edit: Or, as bigmandan pointed out, you could also transform your letter to upper- or lower-case first, then you only have to do one comparison: `($zip[1]).toLowerCase()  == "o"` (Of course this works only in a special case like this – if it was not `O` or `o`, but `a` or `b` instead, you would still have to do individual comparisons.)

Comment: You could use strtoupper on $zip first then you would only have to make one comparison.

Comment: I originally tried strtoupper at the top but thought it wasn't working due to my misunderstanding with the logical operators. Will continue testing, thanks!

Comment: OK using the logical operators as you suggested worked. However, now strtoupper() is failing to capitalize stuff? Any clues?

Comment: There is no `strtoupper` in native JS. And if you mean `toUpperCase` – that _returns_ a modified value, it does not change the original string.